# HUGE performance hit with one-to-one foreign key in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am going to make this REALLY simple.
I have two tables.

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; } //primary key AND foreign key
    //user attributes in here
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
public class UserProfile
{
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; } //primary key AND foreign key
    //profile attributes in here
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Basically they are two tables that share a primary key in a 1-1 relationship. Whether these should be combined into one or not, I don't know, I am basing this off of an existing database.

Now, the issue I have is when I access it.

**THIS CODE GOES FAST(second, maybe two):**

```
List<User> userList; //**This userList is defined elsewhere, but it's a list of about 400 users.
foreach (User user in userList)
{
    var test = user.FirstName;
}
```

**THIS CODE GOES REALLY SLOW(10-30 seconds):**

```
List<User> userList; //**This userList is defined elsewhere, but it's a list of about 400 users.
foreach (User user in userList)
{
    var test = user.UserProfile.EmailAddress;
}
```

Why does my code take so much longer when I access the UserProfile from the user table?!

Comment: Maybe because is making about 400 DB calls whereas the other already had the user objects hydrated? Have you profile the DB to see how many DB calls are made?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably because you are lazy loading `UserProfile` here. This means that for each iteration in your loop you make an individual call to the DB to load `UserProfile` when you attempt to access the email address.

I'm not sure how you are creating the `userList` collection, but assuming you are doing a simple query over your `User` table you can use `Include` to eager load any properties that you would like to have up front:

```
var userList = (from u in dbContext.Users.Include("UserProfile")
                select u)
```

Now the performance hit is limited to when this query is intially executed, enumerating over the results would no longer require individual calls to the DB.

Comment: I am using a User Repository to get the users. My call looks like "return context.User;" from the dbcontext. Is there a way I can still enable eager loading?

Comment: Never mind, my sleepless mind didn't make the connection. One call to return context.User.include("UserProfile") fixed the whole thing! I can't thank you enough! I've been frustrated with this for days trying to narrow down the problem!

Comment: I believe that returning context.User is just a query that hasn't been executed yet.  This means you should be able to just chain the `Include` on to the end of it.  I would have to see your repository code to know more.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to know for sure without the query giving you the `User`s in the question, but this is what I see;

The first query loops though all your `User` objects and prints the FirstName of each.
**1 SQL query.**

The second query loops through all your `User` objects, and for each sends a query to the database to get the `UserProfile` to get access to the EmailAddress.
**401 queries.**

You should read up on lazy loading vs. eager loading.